# Skype for Business Web SDK - participants object empty

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

When creating a meeting via the Skype for Business Web SDK, the `conversation` object contains a `participants` list which contains objects representing the participant details of that meeting. This is working and we can see all the participants that we would expect.

However when **joining** a meeting that someone else has created via the Skype for Business Web SDK, the `participants` list is always empty, despite knowing for a fact that there are other users connected to that meeting.

Is this a bug in the SDK? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: updating with more info after suggestions

we retrieve the `conversation` object using the following code (note we are retrieving it via a URI):

`app.conversationsManager.getConversationByUri(uri);`

Here are the outputs from experimenting with the `conversation` object:

`conversation.participants()` returns `[]`

`conversation.participants` returns `function [Collection: 0 items]`

```
conversation.participants.get().then(function(participants) {
    console.log(participants)
})
```

logs `Promise {task_ccf0d98018eaf: Task}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConversationByUri` doesn't actually join the meeting. It just retrieves a conversation model. You need to actually start one of the services (`conversation.chatService.start()`, `conversation.audioService.start()`, etc) in order to join the meeting. Once you join the meeting the participants collection will get updated with people in the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could prevent seeing the participants in a conversation/meeting:

- Events have not posted indicating who is active
- The collection containing participants has not updated (it is lazy loaded)

If you wanted to get the exact count you would be best served by making a request on the collection similar to:

```
conv.participants.get().then(function (participants) {
    // participants is an array of currently active persons in the conversation/meeting
});
```

You could also keep track locally by listening to the added/removed events on the participants collection.

```
conv.participants.added(function (person) {
    // add to local list...
});

conv.participants.removed(function (person) {
    // remove from local list...
});
```

If this is not the case it would be interesting to know what code you are using to observe the empty list of participants.